# Is it X-majority or majority-X?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

For example,  "majority-Muslim country" vs "Muslim-majority country". Which one is correct? Perhaps both?

Comment: It's more a question of which one carries the implications you wish to convey, and that varies greatly with context and audience.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct enough in English that they would feel natural for most English-speakers to read, but Muslim-majority is more commonly used, so you should probably stick with that, especially if you're writing for academic contexts where people are likely to be familiar with Muslim-majority as a customary phrase. Muslim-majority is more *idiomatic*.

Here's a [Google "ngram" view](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Muslim-majority%2Cmajority-Muslim&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMuslim%20-%20majority%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmajority%20-%20Muslim%3B%2Cc0) of the relative frequency of the two versions.

Note: the phrase is only hyphenated to emphasise that both words together are describing the country. If you want to refer to the group of people making up a Muslim majority within a country, it should be left un-hyphenated, like this:

"The Muslim majority within Indonesia…"

For this phrase, "the majority Muslim within Indonesia…" would be incorrect (because majority is a noun here instead of being part of a compound adjective).